# Error when compliling sass - node and gulp

Tags: npm, gulp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn1OY.jpg)

I'm getting errors using foundation when trying to use gulp.

Please help?

Tried re-running sudo npm install and gulp

I'm using the Foundation Framework: https://get.foundation/

Not seen this error before but when I delete some of the files with errors, I get more erorrs and unable to compile the sass?

Comment: Your installation is fine, this is an error where sass cannot identify your math.abs method, you could perhaps try to wrap it to make sass compute it: `$dividend: #{math.abs($dividend)}`?

Comment: So replace:  $dividend: math.abs($dividend);
with:   $dividend: #{math.abs($dividend)} ?

Comment: I've used the foundation framework before and didnt get these errors?

Comment: I don't think it's part of the framework, it's just a sass-compilation issue? Can't say for sure, I don't use foundation, but the error is clearly SASS-related, not necessarilly framework related. It depends who defines `$dividend`, if its in the framework there's something wrong (maybe the SASS version or the like), if you defined it, you should definitely try to use `#{}` to print the value so sass doesn't think it ends earlier than expected.

Comment: I think its how my mac's set up.  How do I change my sass version?  I've been trying to figure this out for 6 hours now :(. with no luck!

Comment: Run `sass -version` and see if it is higher than `1.65.1`, the one needed by foundation. Otherwise I can't really help either with this, as it should compile tbh.

Comment: It says:
node-sass 8.0.0 (Wrapper) [JavaScript]
libsass   3.5.5 (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]

Comment: Not sure how I can find out my sass version? I'm having to delete all the node_module files for the foundation framework because their erroring